# How can I dynamically define a "value" bind in Svelte?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

I'm new to Svelte, and I'm trying to use it to write a single-page app that will display a form with some field values dynamically calculated based on other fields. Ideally, I'd like to drive the rendering of the form using static JSON configuration files (to make it easy to generate new forms with other tools that output JSON).

I want to be able to dynamically define the relationships between form fields, so that when the user enters values, the computed fields recalculate automatically.

I'd like to end up with something similar to this (but obviously this doesn't work):

```html
<script>
let objFormConfig = JSON.parse(`{
    "formElements": [
        {
              "id": "f1",
              "label": "First value?"
        },
        {
              "id": "f2",
              "label": "Second value?"
        },
        {
               "id": "f2",
               "label": "Calculated automatically",
               "computed": "f1 + f2"
        }
    ]
}`);
</script>
<form>
{#each objFormConfig.formElements as item}
    <div>
        <label for="{item.id}">{item.label}
        {#if item.computed}
            <input type=number id={item.id} value={item.computed} readonly/>
        {:else}
            <input type=number id={item.id} bind:value={item.id}/>
        {/if}
        </label>
    </div>
{/each}
</form>
```

Live (non-working) [REPL example here.](https://svelte.dev/repl/b8f7217a730f462b8b188583bab8d5a4)

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Or if it's completely impossible, could you suggest a different approach?

> One idea I had is to have string keys into a map, and then string names referencing functions that get called to calculate the result, but that feels clunky

Comment: I have two suggestions: 1) use form element components with props like id, label .... and 2) and use the special element <svelte:component) for your dynamic config.

Comment: Thanks! This is a simplified minimal example and I am using a custom <Field /> component (following this example https://svelte.dev/repl/3f161dd253624d4ea7a3b8b9e5763e96?version=3.21.0 ) in the real project. Can you explain how the <svelte:component> would help for this use-case?

Comment: Following the example: the <svelte:component ..> is used in Field.svelte to configure and run the json config as dynamic components. See  Field.svelte line 13.

Comment: That solves part of the problem: creating the form elements from the JSON, but it doesn't set up the reactivity between those elements, which is what I'm really struggling with. I can't see how to specify {field3.value = field1.value + field2.value} in JSON and then have Svelte make that relationship live.

Comment: The example again solves it with a reactive store; using store bindings to bind the form values;

Comment: Yo have to figure out a lot (as a beginner). Become familiair with Svelte first. It will be quite a challenge for you to build something which fullfills all your current and future needs.

Comment: In that example, the author is storing values in the reactive store, but they are not actually demonstrating reactive behaviour between fields. If you look at CheckBox.svelte, line 9, they are only writing a console.log -- it doesn't actually evaluate fDisable as code. Unchecking the checkbox does not disable the TextArea.

Comment: It will be quite a challenge for you to build something which fullfills all your current and future needs.

Comment: @voscausa Thanks for your help! I've gotten to a working result with some of your suggestions.

Comment: Nice. I like the dynamic derived store wich makes use of a dynamic callback (with generated code for the callback function). The function constructor was new for me.You made a lot of progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've come up with a way to achieve the result I wanted. The key insight is using Svelte's [derived stores](https://tj.ie/derived-stores-with-svelte/) feature to capture the dependency relationships between the fields.

You can use the [Function constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Function) to create a function from a JSON string (there may be security issues with this approach—though less serious than `eval()`; in my case the form config is trusted input). Then, you pass that function as a [callback to derived()](https://svelte.dev/docs#derived) and Svelte will make sure it gets automatically reevaluated when the inputs change.

From there, it's relatively straightforward to define Svelte components that [subscribe to the store value](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/auto-subscriptions) using `$`.

Here's what my `stores.ts` file winds up looking like:

```js
import { Writable, writable, derived } from 'svelte/store';
import { fields } from "./sample.json";

export const fieldMap: Map<string, Writable<number>> = new Map();

const computedFields = fields.filter((f) => f.computed);
const userFields = fields.filter((f) => !f.computed);

userFields.forEach((field) => {fieldMap[field.id] = writable(0)})

type JsonFunction = (values: number[]) => number;

for (const cf of computedFields) {
    const fromStatic = new Function(...cf.computed.args, "return " + cf.computed.body);
    const derivedFunction: JsonFunction = (values: number[]) => fromStatic(...values);
    const arg0: Writable<number> = fieldMap[cf.computed.args[0]];
    const moreArgs: Array<Writable<number>> = [];
    for (const arg of cf.computed.args.slice(1)) {
        moreArgs.push(fieldMap[arg]);
    }
    fieldMap[cf.id] = derived([arg0, ...moreArgs], derivedFunction);
};
```

With a `sample.json` that looks like this:

```json
{
  "fields": [
    {
      "label": "First value?",
      "id": "f1"
    },
    {
      "label": "Second value?",
      "id": "f2"
    },
    {
      "label": "Summed",
      "id": "f3",
      "computed": {
        "args": [
          "f1",
          "f2"
        ],
        "body": "f1 + f2"
      }
    },
    {
      "label": "Doubled",
      "id": "f4",
      "computed": {
        "args": [
          "f3"
        ],
        "body": "f3 * 2"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that importing directly from JSON like this requires [enabling the resolveJsonModule](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/importing-json-modules-in-typescript) feature in TypeScript.

You can see [a complete working example here,](https://svelte.dev/repl/b7f49fa6fce04d06977e1ad1d3b21d5a?version=3.28.0) but the Svelte REPL doesn't appear to support TypeScript yet. I've had to remove all the type annotations and rename `sample.json` to `sample.json.js` (which does somewhat defeat the point of the exercise).

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, you can't have a string `f1 + f2` or `ct1.fValue==''`, pass it to `{ expression }`, `bind:`, `class:`, `use:`, `on:` and expect it to work.

Because Svelte doesn't work that way.

Svelte [is a compiler](https://dev.to/joshnuss/svelte-compiler-under-the-hood-4j20).

When you write

```
<!-- expression -->
{ name + name }

<!-- or bind: -->
<input bind:value="{name}" />

<!-- or dynamic attribute -->
<input disabled="name === ''" />

<!-- or many more -->
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/61624b5f0aea4fa9b8e84411be0625f1?version=3.25.1)

if you look at the compiled output JS, you will not see the string `name + name`, `name` or `name === ''`. Whatever variable used in there is analysed and transformed.

You can read my blog ["Compile Svelte in your Head"](https://lihautan.com/compile-svelte-in-your-head-part-1) to understand more on this.

---

Now, as to any suggestion on how to make this work, I would first suggest modifying to JSON configuration files (if possible):

for example, if you have:

```json
{
  "formElements": [
    {
      "id": "f1",
      "label": "First value?"
    },
    {
      "id": "f2",
      "label": "Second value?"
    },
    {
      "id": "f2",
      "label": "Calculated automatically",
      "computed": {
        "type": "sum",
        "variables": ["f1", "f2"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you can implement derived fields via:

```html
<input type=number id={item.id} value={compute(item.computed)} readonly/>
```

You can check out this [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/4984e5d8415d40499008e8bc28d0155c?version=3.25.1)

If it is impossible to modify the formConfig, then you would have to parse and evaluate the expression yourself.

A over-simplified example of parse + evaluate the expression: [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/e09ff62aaf33425c91b518a36216dd04?version=3.25.1). *I wouldn't recommend doing it this way.*

Comment: Thanks, there's a lot of good information here! I'll read your blog post. One clarification: the JSON config I'm hoping to use to build my forms is available at compile-time. I understand this might be impossible if the config were only accessible at runtime.

Comment: @bjmc i didn't quite get the difference between available at compile-time vs runtime, can elaborate more on this?

Comment: For example, if the form JSON were retrieved over an API in the user's browser after/as part of the Svelte app loading, then I would consider that runtime. But that's not what's happening: I will have the form config on disk when I'm running `npm run build`. I believe I could implement this as a pre-processor if I need to, but I'm wondering if I can do it "inside" Svelte.

Comment: what are you referring to, when you say, "inside" svelte? part of the svelte compilation?

Comment: I guess it's sort of arbitrary, but I meant by using the tools Svelte gives us out-of-the-box, without adding something like https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess Anyway, I managed to get a working result, partly using your ideas. I've posted my result as a sibling answer, and I'd welcome any further suggestions. Thanks for the help!